# How can I add authentication module for my Sonos App

Tags: authentication, sonos

My company has a Sonos App on live. They want me to add authentication to the app. I red all the documentation but really its very hard for me, I cant add an authentication / Login module to this App. Maybe someone can help me for do that. Best regards:)

Comment: Best to ask SO for help with a specific question ("Why is this not working for me?") rather than a general how-do-I-do-this?

Answer (score 0):

The [authentication documentation](https://musicpartners.sonos.com/docs?q=node/289) is the best place to start. If you have specific questions about that documentation, you can post them here on SO.

Comment: The documentation I linked has everything you need, and is a very handy step-by-step guide. If you have specific questions, I can certainly help you.

Comment: Ok, actually im searching for a way to sonos ask user Add Account or Has Account. How can I open this feature?

Comment: Have you had a chance to read through the documentation linked above? It contains a step-by-step process. If you have specific questions about functions or APIs, please ask here on SO.